# Text output with a label or non-editable text input

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a Shiny newbie and I have probably a simple question, but I swear I spent half day reading solutions here and can't find anything close to what I need.
Imaging you have a database with employees ID, name, last name, age.
I need to have in my app a text input that allows the user to enter the ID and to see on the same row the name, last name and age.
The problem I face is that textInput will have a label (say "ID").
All the three other fields, that I need to be on the same row, won't have a label.
So what I would need is either a way to add a label to the three textOutput elements or to display them as textInput with a default value that has to change/behave like an output as soon as a user enters a new ID. But how?
This is my sample code:

```
library(shiny) 
u <- fluidPage(   
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),   
  sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(),
                mainPanel(
                          h2("Results"),
                          fluidRow(column(2,
                                          textInput("input_ID", label = "Cusip 1",
                                                    value = "123")),
                                  column(2,
                                         textOutput(outputId = "output_name")),
                                  column(2,
                                         textOutput(outputId = "output_lastname")),
                                  column(2,
                                         textOutput(outputId = "output_age"))
                                  )
                          )
                )
  )

s <- function(input,output){
        output$output_name <- renderText(
          {             # here is where I will check in a database
            paste("Sample Name")   
          })    
        output$output_lastname <- renderText(
          {             # here is where I will check in a database
            paste("Sample Last Name")   
          })
        output$output_age <- renderText(
          {             # here is where I will check in a database
            paste("Sample Age")   
          })
  } 
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

Perhaps I have to use different widgets?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I updated the code to change the label using an textInput as suggested in the comment. Perhaps it helps to understand exactly what you are looking for.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
u <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(
      h2("Results"),
      fluidRow(
        column(2, textInput("input_ID", label = "Cusip 1",value = "123")),
        column(2, textInput("output_name", label = "Firstname") %>% disabled()),
        column(2, textInput("output_lastname", label = "Lastname") %>% disabled()),
        column(2, textInput("output_age", label = "Age") %>% disabled())))))

s <- function(input,output, session){

  observe({
    id <- input$input_ID
    set.seed(id)
    df <- list(firstname = sample(LETTERS, 1), lastname = sample(LETTERS, 1), age = sample(1:100, 1))
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "output_name", label = df[["firstname"]])
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "output_lastname", label = df[["lastname"]])
    updateTextInput(session, inputId = "output_age", label = df[["age"]])
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer but it doesn't solve my problem. If you run your app, where is the label of each output box? how do you know what is the name, last name, and age? That's what I'm trying to achieve. Have a label for the output fields.

Comment: In this case I did not understand your question correctly. Thinking about this, I am not sure how exactly you want the app to behave. If if helps, you might use `textInput` as "output" and update the label with `updateTextInput`. You can also disable it with `shinyjs::disable`.

Comment: that actually does answer my question! So try to visualize 4 fields on the same row. One is an input and 3 are outputs. All 4 fields need a label (ID, Name, Last Name, Age). These labels are all aligned on web page at the same height. Then, all have a value, with the simple difference the first field is an input and the other three are outputs. And again, these values have to be aligned at the same height. If we use textOutput, we won't have their labels. your solution helps. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear this helped.

Answer (score 0):

How I create label for my UI is simply adding a h3 tag above each textoutput:

```
library(shiny) 
u <- fluidPage(   
  titlePanel("Simple Selectable Reactive Function"),   
  sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(),
                mainPanel(
                          h2("Results"),
                          fluidRow(column(2,
                                          textInput("input_ID", label = "Cusip 1",
                                                    value = "123")),
                                  column(2,
                                         h3("First Name: "),
                                         textOutput(outputId = "output_name")),
                                  column(2,
                                         h3("Last Name: "),
                                         textOutput(outputId = "output_lastname")),
                                  column(2,
                                         h3("Age: ),
                                         textOutput(outputId = "output_age"))
                                  )
                          )
                )
  )
```